# Angular-Bootstrap Datepicker - Keep Today's date highlighted when another date is selected

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

*Note*: I checked it in SO and could not find any Question/Response that help related to this issue. Please guide me if it already exists.

I am using Angular Bootstrap's ui-datepicker library.

I am currently embedding the calender on the page. I am using angular.js, Bootstrap.css

- Highlight today's date by default
- Select another date will highlight the selected date. **But, losing the highlight for the today's date.**
- Disable the previous dates in the respective month.

Here is the sample code:

```
<div ng-controller="DatepickerDemoCtrl">
  <pre>Selected date is: <em>{{dt | date:'fullDate' }}</em></pre>

  <div style="display:inline-block; min-height:290px;">
    <datepicker ng-model="dt" min-date="minDate" show-weeks="true" class="well well-sm" custom-class="getDayClass(date, mode)"></datepicker>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the [Link to Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/wVPK4m50tElAWLz9xCTE?p=preview)

Any suggestions (regarding highlight today date when i select another date) will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `custom-class(date, mode)` attribute. You actually already use it in your plunker. In this attribute you can include an expression that will return a custom class based on passing date and mode.

In your case you correctly define this attribute in `datepicker` element:

```
<datepicker ng-model="dt" min-date="minDate" 
    show-weeks="true" class="well well-sm" 
    custom-class="getDayClass(date, mode)"></datepicker>
```

You just have to change `getDayClass` function and make it do what you want to do: return a css class that highlights current date's button no matter what date is selected in datepicker.

```
$scope.getDayClass = function(date, mode) {
    if (mode === 'day') {
      var dayToCheck = new Date(date).setHours(0,0,0,0);
      var currentDay = new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0);

      if (dayToCheck === currentDay) {
         return 'highlight-current-date'; 
      }
   }

   return '';
};
```

Of course, add `highlight-current-date` class to you css file.

```
.highlight-current-date button {
  background: aqua;
}
```

Check updated plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/tu1OhkHgw2o2QkZujuWl?p=preview).

Comment: Hi, I'm looking for the same solution to highlight the current date whether the user clicks on another date button, but in my case I'm using datepicker popup, I'm unable to achieve through it. Can anyone provide me solution for the same.