# ng-class vs custom-class for AngularJS datepicker

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker

I'm basing my question [on this StackOverflow piece](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30176500/angular-bootstrap-datepicker-keep-todays-date-highlighted-when-another-date-i) where the additional twist is that I'm getting the dates for which I apply the special class (e.g. `highlight-current-date`) from a `$http` request.

The problem is that the `$http` request returns the events too late for `getDayClass()` to apply. So for example if I switch the month back and forth, `getDayClass()` picks up the dates returned by the `$http` request.　I considered using `ng-class` instead, but then the classes don't seem to apply to the individual dates in the calendar. What gives? Various combinations of embedding things inside the other don't work either.

**Controller**

```
    $scope.events = [];
    $http({
        url: "getevents.php",
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
    }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        if (data !== undefined) {
            $scope.events = data;
        }
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.status = status;
    });

    $scope.getDayClass = function(date) {
        var dayToCheck = new Date(date).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.events.length; i++) {
            var currentDay = new Date(Date.parse($scope.events[
                i].date)).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
            if (dayToCheck === currentDay) {
                return $scope.events[i].status;
            }
        }
        return '';
    };
```

**UI**

```
<datepicker ng-model="dt" min-date="minDate" 
    show-weeks="true" class="well well-sm" 
    custom-class="getDayClass(date, mode)"></datepicker>
```

**Update**: the issue is that the getDayClass gets fired with a date parameter when the datepicker UI (calendar) loads. If I implement the solution proposed by Sundar below, getDayClass does get fired with right events, but the date variable is undefined, so the classes don't get assigned.

Answer (score 0):

http requests are asynchronous.they wont get executed synchronously like other function calls.so if you want to do any operation that needs to be executed after the http request you need to add that in success or then methods.

change your code like below

```
$scope.events = [];
    $http({
        url: "getevents.php",
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
    }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        if (data !== undefined) {
            $scope.events = data;
            $scope.getDayClass(); //call functions that requires event 
        }
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.status = status;
    });

    $scope.getDayClass = function(date) {
        var dayToCheck = new Date(date).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.events.length; i++) {
            var currentDay = new Date(Date.parse($scope.events[
                i].date)).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
            if (dayToCheck === currentDay) {
                return $scope.events[i].status;
            }
        }
        return '';
    };
```

Comment: Yeah, I thought this might work but it doesn't. By the time getDayClass() gets called from the http request, the date parameter in getDayClass is undefined.

Comment: set ur date parameter.how do i know which dates will get passed?

Comment: while calling that method add date which you want to add

Comment: I think the key part is that the UI has 

<datepicker ng-model="dt" min-date="minDate" 
    show-weeks="true" class="well well-sm" 
    custom-class="getDayClass(date, mode)"></datepicker>

which means it gets loaded once, and the dates passed in, when the UI is rendered.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100875/discussion-between-rio-and-sundar).